# Is there any difference when using AVX2 on the stack and the heap?

Tags: c, simd, avx2

In this example I'm adding two arrays using AVX2. If I declare the arrays on the stack, it all works as expected. However, when the memory is allocated on the heap it compiles, but throws a Segmentation Fault at runtime.

Compilation succeeds but throws the following warning:

```
 AVX vector return without AVX enabled changes the ABI [-Wpsabi]
```

I'm trying this on a i7-8550U with AVX2 support, and compiling with the flags: `-march=native -mavx2`.

Here is a minimal example using static memory:

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    __attribute__((aligned(32))) uint32_t buffer1[8];
    __attribute__((aligned(32))) uint32_t buffer2[8];
    __attribute__((aligned(32))) uint32_t buffer3[8];

    __m256i* buffer1_s = (__m256i*)buffer1;
    __m256i* buffer2_s = (__m256i*)buffer2;
    __m256i* buffer3_s = (__m256i*)buffer3;

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        buffer1[i] = rand() % 64;
        buffer2[i] = rand() % 64;
    }

    *buffer3_s = _mm256_add_epi32(*buffer1_s, *buffer2_s);

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", buffer1[i]);
        printf("%d ", buffer2[i]);
        printf("%d ", buffer3[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

And here a broken one allocating dynamic memory:

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    __attribute__((aligned(32))) uint32_t* buffer1 = malloc(8 * sizeof(uint32_t));
    __attribute__((aligned(32))) uint32_t* buffer2 = malloc(8 * sizeof(uint32_t));
    __attribute__((aligned(32))) uint32_t* buffer3 = malloc(8 * sizeof(uint32_t));

    __m256i* buffer1_s = (__m256i*)buffer1;
    __m256i* buffer2_s = (__m256i*)buffer2;
    __m256i* buffer3_s = (__m256i*)buffer3;

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        buffer1[i] = rand() % 64;
        buffer2[i] = rand() % 64;
    }

    *buffer3_s = _mm256_add_epi32(*buffer1_s, *buffer2_s);

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", buffer1[i]);
        printf("%d ", buffer2[i]);
        printf("%d ", buffer3[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(buffer1);
    free(buffer2);
    free(buffer3);
}
```

They are both compiled with:

```
gcc -O0 -g -march=native -mavx2 -o test_avx2 test_avx2.c
```

- What is causing the segmentation fault?
- What would be the correct way to use AVX2 on memory that's been malloc'd?

**Solution:**

Memory needs to be allocated with the correct alignment. The compiler attribute is not enough to force the compiler to do it.

```
__attribute__((aligned(32))) uint32_t* buffer1 = malloc(8 * sizeof(uint32_t));
```

should instead be

```
uint32_t* buffer1 = aligned_alloc(32, 8 * sizeof(uint32_t));
```

Comment: Do you want to know how to do this with the allocation as it is (unaligned, the attribute doesn't change what `malloc` does) or how to align the allocation?

Comment: No, there's no difference in performance or anything, it just depends on the alignment of the memory you're actually loading/storing.

Comment: @harold I'm just confused why this is segfaulting, but I believe you've already spotted the issue. I believe I should be using memalign (or something alike) instead of a simple malloc. Is that right? Basically it's not enough with the attribute but I also need the correct allocation function, right?

Comment: @orientnab yes, also you can then remove the attribute, it controls the alignment of the variable but that doesn't matter when it's only a pointer to the buffer instead of the buffer itself

Comment: Awesome, just fixed the question and added a solution. The solution can be found in the linked post, however, there was no way to see they were related without knowing that the issue was related to alignment. Thanks, everyone. (Not sure how to close the post now.)